# how can I group sum and count with sequel ORM and postgresl?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

This is too tough for me guys. It's for Jeremy!

I have two tables (although I can also envision needing to join a third table) and I want to sum one field and count rows, in the same, table while joining with another table and return the result in json format.

First of all, the data type field that needs to be summed, is numeric(10,2) and the data is inserted as `params['amount'].to_f`.

The tables are expense_projects which has the name of the project and the company id and expense_items which has the company_id, item and amount (to mention just the critical columns) - the "company_id" columns are disambiguated.

So, the following code:

```
expense_items = DB[:expense_projects].left_join(:expense_items, :expense_project_id => :project_id).where(:project_company_id => company_id).to_a.to_json
```

works fine but when I add

```
expense_total = expense_items.sum(:amount).to_f.to_json
```

I get an error message which says

```
TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer:
```

so, the first question is why and how can this be fixed?

Then I want to join the two tables and get all the project names form the left (first table) and sum amount and count items in the second table. I have tried

```
DB[:expense_projects].left_join(:expense_items, :expense_items_company_id => expense_projects_company_id).count(:item).sum(:amount).to_json
```

and variations of this, all of which fails.

I would like a result which gets all the project names (even if there are no expense entries and returns something like:

```
project  item_count item_amount
pr 1      7           34.87
pr 2      0           0
```

and so on. How can this be achieved with one query returning the result in json format?

Many thanks, guys.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out, I hope this helps somebody else:

```
DB[:expense_projects___p].where(:project_company_id=>user_company_id).
  left_join(:expense_items___i, :expense_project_id=>:project_id).
  select_group(:p__project_name).
  select_more{count(:i__item_id)}.
  select_more{sum(:i__amount)}.to_a.to_json
```